# PHP rtrim ".php"

Tags: php

I want to remove ".php" from the end of a string if it exists. Consider this:

```
$filename = 'index';
rtrim($filename,".php");//returns "index"

$filename = 'search';
rtrim($filename,".php");//returns "searc"
```

Why is this happening? I feel like it has something to do with ending with the letter 'h' - 'h' being in the string in rtrim. So I tried a regular expression (`.php$`) to see if it made a difference but it didn't.

Comment: use `basename($filename, '.php')` instead, or the pathname() function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`rtrim` accepts a **list of characters** as the second argument, so in this case, it will trim not just the `.php` extension, but any `.`, `p`, or `h` characters found in the rest of the string.

Try using `preg_replace("/(.+)\.php$/", "$1", $filename);` instead, or `basename($filename, '.php')` if you have the file on the server, not just in a string.

Comment: Thanks. My misunderstanding of rtrim which I had usually just used for whitespace. Thanks for going the extra mile and giving me the preg_replace.

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to `rtrim` is a string with a list of characters. In this case, it will strip off any P, H, and . in your string, so returning searc.

Answer (score 1):

if you're simply trying to remove the extension, why not use this:
    $filename = 'index.php';
    $name = strstr($filename, '.', true);